# Android 14 Exception While starting foreground service with foreground types

Tags: android, kotlin, service, android-14

I'm trying to change my call app for OS14 behavioral changes.
App works fine when app is in foreground state.This is the code block used to start the foreground service.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                LogMessage.d(TAG,"#startForeground  handleForegroundPermissionForIncomingCallNotification")
                startForeground(
                    getIncomingCallNotificationId(),
                    getIncomingCallNotification(this, getCallType(), isFullScreenIntent, callUsers),
                    FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_ALLOWED_SINCE_Q
                )
```

So in foreground above app code works fine and when i move to background state and it works fine too.But when app is in kill state,i'm getting the below exceptions.

> #startForeground Exception while trying to start foreground handleForegroundPermissionForIncomingCallNotification!!
> Starting FGS with type camera callerApp=ProcessRecord{7e55d22
> 12942:com.uikit.dev/u0a190} targetSDK=34 requires
> permissions: all of the permissions allOf=true
> [android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_CAMERA] any of the permissions
> allOf=false [android.permission.CAMERA,
> android.permission.SYSTEM_CAMERA]  and the app must be in the eligible
> state/exemptions to access the foreground only permission

So when checking android docs
https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/services/foreground-services#wiu-restrictions

I could see that

> For while-in-use permissions, this causes a potential problem. If your
> app has a while-in-use permission, it only has that permission while
> it's in the foreground. This means if your app is in the background,
> and it tries to create a foreground service of type camera, location,
> or microphone, the system sees that your app doesn't currently have
> the required permissions, and it throws a SecurityException.

So i'm just stuck here not knowing how to create service while in background where my app needs newly introduced foreground service types.